# How to send a file or stream with Slim?

Tags: php, curl, stream, slim

The following endpoint successfully receives a file from a browser.  I next wish to send this file or stream to another server which happens to be also using Slim.  I obviously know how to receive the file on the other server as I have done so here, but don't know how to send this file/stream to the other server.  How is this accomplished.  Thank you

```
$app->post(_VER_.'/tools/import', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    if (empty($files['file'])) {
        throw new \Exception('"file" is missing');
    }

    $file = $files['file'];
    syslog(LOG_INFO, 'name: '.$file->getClientFilename().' type: '.$file->getClientMediaType().' size: '.$file->getSize());
    $stream=$file->getStream();
    syslog(LOG_INFO, 'stream size: '.$stream->getSize());
});
```

output:

```
Oct 14 13:19:18 devServer API[62322]: name: report (17).csv type: application/vnd.ms-excel size: 451090
Oct 14 13:19:18 devServer API[62322]: stream size: 451090
```

Comment: The question is how do you want to send the file to the other server? Over http, ftp etc?

Comment: @DanielO  Good point.  Sorry.  Using HTTP.

Comment: With curl it's possible to implement a http file upload. Here is an [example](http://code.iamkate.com/php/sending-files-using-curl/).

Comment: @DanielO  Yes, I can do so from scratch, but didn't know whether there was a "Slim" way to do so.  PS. One should use `CURLFile`.

Comment: Afaik, there this no specific Slim way, because Slim is not responsible for such kind of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that slim can do by itself. You will need to either use CURL directly or a library like [guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle).

With guzzle you could do something like this:

```
$guzzleClient->request(
    'POST',
    'http://yourserveraddress.com/post',
    ['body' => $file->getStream()]
);
```

You can read more about how to upload files with guzzle [here in the documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#uploading-data).